# Convexity with certain properties implies a function is monotone

Tags: convex-analysis

Why if $f$ is convex and $ a \ge 0 $ the the function $g(x)=f(x+a)-f(x)$ is increasing.

[Attempt] I was thinking about the following property of convex functions: If $x\lt y \lt z$ then $$ \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} \le \frac{f(y)-f(z)}{y-z}$$
but I don't  know how to get to $x+a$ and $y+a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x\le y$. Then $y$ is between $x$ and $y+a$, i.e.,
$$
y = \lambda x + (1-\lambda) (y+a) 
$$
for some $\lambda \in (0,1)$.
Rearranging yields $\lambda y = \lambda x + (1-\lambda)a$
and
$$
x+a = \lambda ( y+a) + (1-\lambda) x,
$$
so that $x+a$ is a convex combination of $x$ and $y+a$, with the same coefficients as $y$ is a convex combination of $x$ and $y+a$.

By convexity, we get
$$
f(y) \le \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y+a)
$$
and
$$ 
f(x+a) \le \lambda f(y+a) + (1-\lambda) f(x).
$$
Adding both inequalities results in
$$
f(x+a) + f(y) \le f(y+a)  + f(x)$,
$$
or equivalently,
$$
f(x+a) - f(x) \le f(y+a) - f(y),
$$
and $x\mapsto f(x+a)-f(x)$ is monotonically increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Convexity of $f$ implies $f'$ nondecreasing as well as
$$x\mapsto f(x+a)-f(x)=\int_0^af'(t+x)dt.$$